# New HTML5 Apex:Input issue

Tags: date, inputfield, html5

I'm trying to use new Input and InputField with type attribute.
I need to use the date or datetime type as follow:

```
<apex:input value="{!birthdayDate}" type="date" styleClass="select-box"/>
```

with corresponding controller:

```
public Date birthdayDate {
    get;
    set {
        System.debug('birthdayDate setter: ' + value);
        birthdayDate = value;
        currentAccount.PersonBirthdate = value;
    }
}
```

But when the user clears the field by clicking on the "x" button, the setter is not triggered and value cannot be reset.

I could use the inputField instead directly on PersonBithdate field, but I get an "Error: Invalid Date" when submitting the form.

FYI : I'm using API 29 (as requested by the Winter 14 release notes) for this files.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

See http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/New-HTML5-Apex-Input-issue/m-p/698847#M70703.  Fixed in next release.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think the type of PersonBithdate is not date,so you see the error when submitting the form.